# Matlab 2014b mex and Visual Studio 2013 default output directory

Tags: matlab, visual-studio

I am trying to generate Matlab mex files using Matlab 2014b and Visual Studio 2013 as the compiler for simple C++ files.  The problem is that the Matlab mex command to simply compile a C++ file such as "mex -c test.cpp" works but puts the output test.obj file in another folder on my computer, c:\Bogle, not in the local matlab folder where the file is or the current pwd.

Where is this default output folder defined?  Is it defined in VS or in Matlab, possibly a windows environment variable?  I know I can use the "-outdir" flag in the mex command but I don't want to have to change the code I got from someone else.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Weird, I get everything in the folder where I compile it

Comment: I experienced that behavior in a totally different scenario with another compiler, when the build folder was close to the maximum allowed path length

Comment: I'm pretty certain that this is something defined with VS settings somewhere.  I reinstalled Matlab for another reason and the behavior is the same.